# Why Runspace in Powershell scripts in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, runspace

I want to be clear about one thing that why we are using `Runspace` while running the PowerShell scripts in `C#`. It runs even though the absence of `Runspace`.

If it can be run without the `Runspace` why we need?

For eg:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript("Import-Module AzureAD");
```

This will work even though the absence of `Runspace`. So Why is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runspace provides APIs for creating pipelines, access session state etc.

When using `PowerShell`, we need to use `System.Management.Automation.PowerShell`, it is using `System.Management.Automation.Runspaces`.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

namespace System.Management.Automation
{
    public sealed class PowerShell : IDisposable
    {
        ......
    }
}
```

Comment: By default, which Runspace session will be created?

Comment: @SaravananKS I am not sure, but [`InitialSessionState `](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.initialsessionstate?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) allows you to define the set of elements that should be present when Session State is created.